# Position absolute and float left issue using multiple divs

Tags: html, css

Lets suppose that I have `n` classes, each of them must have a position absolute and float left.

```css
.test {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
```

IF i use this code the string "test" is one above the other.   BUt i want to align them side by side. I must use `position:absolute`. IS there a way to do that ?

Comment: Your missing a " speech mark at the end of your test classes. If you want to align them side by side position them with the attributes top, bottom, left and right.

Comment: Why do you NEED to use absolute? Whats the purpose of it?

Comment: Could you explain why you *must* use `position: absolute`?

Comment: I want to know to test it is possible to do it ? I know maybe it is not the right way, but i want to know. is there a problem that want to know ? thx

Comment: FYI `position:absolute;` and `float` can't be used together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I think of it with the constraint of having `position: absolute` is to set a width to each of the `div` and give them a position accordingly.

Colors are only to show how each div stretches.

```css
.test1,
.test2,
.test3,
.test4 {
  position:absolute;
  width: 50px;
}

.test1 {
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.test2 {
  left: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.test3 {
  left: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.test4 {
  left: 150px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">test1</div>
<div class="test2">test2</div>
<div class="test3">test3</div>
<div class="test4">test4</div>
```

Comment: This is a "static version", but I said If i have N classes "test". Can i be done using just css ?

Comment: I am afraid not. Since they all would have the same class. When you use `position: absolute`, you are literally placing the element at a position, considering the screen a grid. If you want to place different items at different positions, you cant do that together.

Comment: You have either identify each one separately and position them according.
I dont really understand why you need `position: absolute`, but maybe you can enclose all the `div`s in a wrapper `div`. Mark the parent div as position absolute and align all the inner divs with a simple `display: inline-block`. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST use position:absolute I can't see a way to do it with CSS only.
One thing you can do, is to calculate each item position dynamically in JS and add each DIV the following code:

```
var translate3D =  "translate3d(" + translateX + "px," + translateY + "px,0px)";

var elementStylePointer = elementDom.style;
elementStylePointer.webkitTransform = translate3D;
elementStylePointer.transform = translate3D;
```

This way you can have N divs and each one will get the X,Y coordinates you will calculate before the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

you can add parent absolute to you test.

```css
.abs{
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:100px;
}
.test{
  float:left;
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="abs">
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
</div>
```